# Is Google Play subscription dialog broken (truncated title)?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

The Google Play subscription purchase dialog seems to truncate the title.

I have a yet-unreleased app in alpha release in the dev console, with both subscriptions and one-time purchases.  I implemented Google Play IAB v3, (an upgrade from v2 in another app).  So far, the item display seems to show most of the title, but the subscription dialog truncates the title needlessly.  There's more space to show the full title.  It shows more text in landscape, but still not the full title.

I am doing this testing on a Nexus 5 so far, which I would expect would be a device they tested...

I know that the Google Play subscriptions in v3 IAB aren't used as much as purchases, but there doesn't seem to be any information on this.  Has anybody else seen this behavior?  It seems to be a rather fundamental failure, and would likely limit sales quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google knows about this issue... they say "...titles should be no longer than 25 characters; however, titles can be up to 55 characters in length."

I used almost the entire 55 characters, which is why the problem was clear to me.

I found that note in the docs, as it is not mentioned in the Developer Console:  https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

So, it seems that the solution is to self-limit to 25 characters because it's hit-or-miss when the rest will get displayed, as there is no mechanism to expand the description to show the whole thing.  It's not much good if users see more in landscape mode than portrait (or on some devices), because I don't want user experience to be up to chance...